# Generic pattern algorithms (language agnostic)

Tags: algorithm, tesselation

I'm sorry to ask such a vague and generic question, but I need to write a set of tools that will aid people in creating 2D and 3D geometric patterns.

Does anyone know any good online resources that discuss pattern logic and algorithms (Wikipedia call it [tesselations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellations))?

Much obliged,
David

Comment: @Bart, these tools are supposed to allow people to design visual and structural patterns in a 3D modeler. Probably mostly architects, but I'm not ruling out product designers, jewelers and marine engineers.

Think of someone who wants to place a collection of hexagons on a doubly curved surface for example. What generic algorithms can I expose that will make this task easier? I'm looking for resources that explain how stacking, deformations, etc. can be approached from a programmatic point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take this:

1. I'm sorry to ask such a vague and
   generic question, but I need to
   write a set of tools that will aid
   people in creating 2D and 3D
   geometric patterns.

You're not sorry, you are apologizing - there is a difference. The only dumb question is one you should have asked and didn't, see Smith's Law. There are a few tools, you will have to do some work if you want to write them yourself. I suggest Java as it's popularity as a research platform makes it likely good work is available plus is has run-time bumpers that make it useful as a sand-boxing tool for preliminary work.

2. Does anyone know any good online
   resources that discuss pattern logic
   and algorithms (Wikipedia call it
   tesselations)?

Looks like you already found it.

Comment: @Nicholas, I don't know why you got downvoted twice, I make it a point never to punish those who try and help me. "I am sorry to" is an apology, that's how english works. I'm not opposed to writing anything myself, it's my job, it's what I enjoy. I am merely looking for solid programmer targeted resources. Practically everything I found so far is either targeted at mathematicians or artists.

Comment: ps. The question is language agnostic, but I don't have a choice in my language. It has to be either C# or VB.NET. However, since I'm not asking for specific solutions or example code I thought it wise to not pigeonhole the question with that.

Comment: Not sure why the minus stuff, vaguely speaking those who cannot grasp something will hammer at it in an attempt to understand it plus there is as will code-camp wars in which will flame and attack for no reason. I have a tremendous collection of hours dealing with situations in which there is no room for maneuver nor route of escape, hence the remark about apologetics and nomenclature.

As you note, the web - aptly named - is ruled prima-facia by mathematicians and artists - who will downvote anything that is not nano-meter portal. 

Ok, on the language restraint - you can portal the Java ...

Comment: @Nicholas, :)   Yes, I can read languages with semi-colons and port them. I very much dislike to port code I do not understand (debugging is *such* a pain). My ideal resource is either written in pseudo-code or -even better- proper English.

Comment: How about www.bakhter.com/html/2d/animation_tools.html

Comment: @David, ok - I was trying to look at my stats and so on and get a grasp of how the site works as we are going to get some takedowns by edge conditions but given your replies and where your original post wants to go what I suggest doing is looking at Robert Sedgewick, especially Algorithms in Java - It's really where you want to go. Your original question will get to this eventually, the Author has the work in other programming languages as well and discusses the matter in such a way that fundamental cs notions are before which language, programming gui's is notoriously involved.